# array of objects with 6 keys, how to group them into fewer keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

sorry if the title is a bit missleading, I new to js so idk how to explain what I want to do properly so I'm gonna show my code and what I expect instead.

so I have this array of objects

```
const mi_array = [{
    text: "1st title",
    col2015: 81.8,
    col2016: 86.4,
    col2017: 67.3,
    col2018: 70.8,
    col2019: 67.6
},{
    text: "2nd title",
    col2015: 90.8,
    col2016: 67.4,
    col2017: 39.3,
    col2018: 50.8,
    col2019: 95.6
}];
```

I need something like this

```
const new_array = [{
    name: "1st title",
    data: [81.8,86.4,67.3,70.8,67.6]
},{
    name: "2nd title",
    data: [90.8,67.4,39.3,50.8,95.6]
}];
```

I've been searching on how to do it but this is all I found so far and it comes close to what I need but not quite there yet

```
const new_array = [];

mi_array.forEach(value => {
    for (let key in value) {
        new_array.push(value[key]);
    }
});

console.log(new_array);
```

But my output it's this

```
["1st title", 81.8, 86.4, 67.3, 70.8, 67.6, "2nd title", 90.8, 67.4, 39.3, 50.8, 95.6];
```

Comment: Upvoted for humbly submitting your expectations and your "_not quite there yet_" attempt, which lets us know exactly where you're at in your understanding of the task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the array and create a new object, where the `data` property is the numeric property values of the original.

```js
const mi_array=[{text:"1st title",col2015:81.8,col2016:86.4,col2017:67.3,col2018:70.8,col2019:67.6},{text:"2nd title",col2015:90.8,col2016:67.4,col2017:39.3,col2018:50.8,col2019:95.6}];

const result = mi_array.map(e => ({
  name: e.text,
  data: Object.values(e).filter(e => typeof e == 'number')
}))

console.log(result)
```